Are the two definitions of fppf topology on the category of schemes the same?
Consider the definition of fppf (pre)topology on the category of schemes $\mathrm{Sch}$.
Maybe, most textbooks define an fppf covering of $U\in\mathrm{Sch}$ as a family of morphisms $\mathscr{U} = \{f_i\colon U_i\to U\}_{i\in I}$ such that each $f_i$ is flat and locally of finite presentation and $U=\bigcup_{i\in I}f_i(U_i)$.
On the other hand, in the textbook “Algebraic Spaces” by Knutson, an fppf covering of $U\in\mathrm{Sch}$ is defined as a family of morphisms $\mathscr{U} = \{f_i\colon U_i \to U\}_{i\in I}$ such that each $f_i$ is flat and locally of finite presentation and $\mathscr{U}$ is a universal effective epimorphic family.
I wonder if the two definitions are the same. I observed that, in our situation, $\{U_i\to U\}_{i\in I}$ is a universal effective epimorphic family if and only if the induced morphism $\coprod_{i\in I}U_i \to U$ is a universal effective epimorphism. This is due to the fact that, in the category of schemes, every disjoint union is stable under pullback.
Could someone help me?

If you have a flat morphism locally of finite presentation (fppf) then indeed it is surjective if and only if it is universally effective epimorphic. But this requires proof.

Thank you. When I looked it up, a proof of the "only if" part came up. How is the "if" part proven?

That is the easy part, no? Surjectivity is local on the base so we may assume $U$ is affine, and actually we can further reduce to the case of the spectrum of a field $K$. Then you just have to show that any $K$-scheme that is faithfully flat over $K$ has a point.

Oh, I understand. Thank you for your perfect answer.

Let me expand on my comments.

Assuming a morphism is flat and locally of finite presentation, it is surjective if and only if it is a universally effective epimorphism.

A morphism $f : X \to Y$ of schemes is surjective if and only if for every field $L$ and every morphism $y : \operatorname{Spec} L \to Y$ there is a field extension $L \to K$ and a morphism $x : \operatorname{Spec} K \to X$ making the following diagram commute:
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\operatorname{Spec} K @>x>> X \\
@VVV @VV{f}V \\
\operatorname{Spec} L @>>y> Y 
\end{CD}$$
Therefore, if every effective epimorphism $X' \to \operatorname{Spec} L$ is surjective, then universally effective epimorphisms are surjective.
This argument also shows that the class of surjective morphisms is closed under pullback (a.k.a. base change).

Since the class of flat morphisms locally of finite presentation is closed under pullback, the above implies the class of surjective flat morphisms locally of finite presentation is also closed under pullback.
Thus, if surjective flat morphisms locally of finite presentation are effective epimorphisms, then they are universally effective epimorphisms.

By a somewhat tedious calculation, it can be shown that surjective flat morphisms locally of finite presentation are effective epimorphisms.
This has two parts: an algebraic part (faithfully flat ring extensions) and a topological part (gluing, a.k.a. descent).
The hypothesis of local finite presentation can be weakened without making the proof much harder; what is crucial is that we have a morphism that is obtained by gluing surjective flat morphisms of affine schemes in a controlled way.

It remains to be shown that every effective epimorphism $X' \to \operatorname{Spec} L$ is surjective.
Well, the only way a morphism $X' \to \operatorname{Spec} L$ could fail to be surjective is if $X' = \emptyset$.
But $\emptyset \to \operatorname{Spec} L$ is not even an epimorphism.


